# Can you back up Outlook calendar when upgrading?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have Outlook 2016 and will be upgrading to Outlook 2021.

When I have upgraded other computers recently, the installer would not install over the top of Office 2016 but wanted it completely uninstalled before installing Office 2021.

I have a number of calendar entries in Outlook 2016 which I'd rather not lose when I uninstall so is it possible to backup or save the calendar so that the entries are available after installing Outlook 2021?

Thanks

Comment: Uninstalling Outlook 2016 shouldn't remove your profile.  However, I suspect your profile, is actually an Exchange account. In other words it's unnecessary to backup your Outlook calendar since it won't be lost when you upgrade.  You can save your calendar, if you truly want to, through `File -> Save Calendar` but again it's not necessary.

Comment: And if not using Exchange, back up the PST file to be sure, but reinstalling Office does not lose Email, Calendar, Contacts or Documents.

Comment: @Ramhound - you should post your comments as an answer.

Comment: @John - When the author’s configuration is clear I will do exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Ramhound, if you use an Exchange account, you do not need to back up.

If you need to back up the calendar, please refer to this article: [Export or backup email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91).